# Manipulating the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, fibonacci

Consider the following code that prints out the first 10 Fibonacci numbers.

```
public class Fib {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int f = 0;
        int g = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(f + " ");
            f = f + g;
            g = f - g;
        } 
        System.out.println();   
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this code run only when a positive integer is given by the user and display an error message if the integer is negative? I have considered using a little IF statement or do while at the beginning, but am not sure how to implement it with this particular program.

Comment: What research have you done?  This would have to be one of the most common newbie patterns there is.

Comment: What is it that you aren't sure how to implement? How to read a numeric value from the command line arguments?

Comment: where in this code are you inputting integers through the user?

Comment: You don't have to answer if you don't want to.

Comment: @Hustl3r28: That's not the point that Peter was trying to make. What he meant is that you should attempt a solution yourself and then ask about problems you had during the attempt. That way you will learn more

Comment: More specifically, if we don't know where you're stuck, we don't know what to explain.

Comment: Well, thanks guys for making me stop being lazy and I figured it out. I put in a scanner to receive an integer from the user at the beginning of the program, and did an IF statement where the first part  displays an error message if a negative integer is entered by the user, whilst the subsequent ELSE  handled the FOR LOOP in the above code. Wasn't as difficult as I imagined.

Comment: For a negative integer (-n), the Fibonacci number is Fib(-n)=(-1)^(n+1)*Fib(n), so Fib(-1)=1, Fib(-2)=-1, Fib(-3)=2, Fib(-4)=-3 etc. So you can (but that's just an option) give a valid answer also for negative inputs.